# after a loop how to give task dependencies for some independent static tasks. Airflow

Tags: python, airflow

I have a for loop and I have some intermediate task and some task after the loop as well.

I am giving task dependency in for loop only as mentioned in so many posts:

Example :

```
individual_task1 = SSHOperator (task_id='tk_one'....)

individual_task2 = SSHOperator (task_id='tk_two'....)

individual_task3 = SSHOperator (task_id='tk_three'....)

  for i in [val1,val2,val3,val4.....valn]

    first_task_in_loop = SSHSparkSubmitOperator (task_id='comp_' + i,...)

    second_task_in_loop = SSHOperator(task_id='stats_' + i...)

    individual_task1 >> first_task_in_loop >> second_task_in_loop >> individual_task2 >> individual_task3
```

but for individual_task2 and individual_task3 i get error:

> Broken Dag ,,  task_id already registered .

But that is an individual task not defined in loop then why i am getting this error or i am doing anything wrong?

Comment: Are the `task_id` values for "individual_task2" and "individual_task3" unique?  That exception is thrown because there are multiple tasks in the same DAG with the same `task_id`.

Comment: Yes i understand the cause of that error , task id's are unique for each task.

Comment: Would you mind sharing your full DAG code? Of course, scrubbed for sensitive info.  I can't reproduce this issue with the pseudocode that's provided in the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this:

```
individual_task1 = SSHOperator (task_id='tk_one'....)

individual_task2 = SSHOperator (task_id='tk_two'....)

individual_task3 = SSHOperator (task_id='tk_three'....)

  for i in [val1,val2,val3,val4.....valn]

    first_task_in_loop = SSHSparkSubmitOperator (task_id='comp_' + i,...)

    second_task_in_loop = SSHOperator(task_id='stats_' + i...)

    individual_task1 >> first_task_in_loop >> second_task_in_loop >> individual_task2

individual_task2 >> individual_task3
```

maybe Airflow is complaining because you are setting the same task flow many times

Comment: Thanks @lealvcon , its working like charm now. That was the exact issue. Thanks a lot. I accepted your answer.